# How to move activity to another activity with specific fragment target?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way that from the activity i want to go to another activity with multiple fragment and select a fragment that i want to focus it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to move from `Actvity A` to `Activity B` and make `Activity B` show a particular fragment. You need to pass an extra containing some form of identity(Eg. the name you gave to your fragment) of the fragment you want to show to `Activity B`. Then in `onCreate` in `Activity B` read the extra you passed to it to determine which fragment to setup in `Activity B`